# Serialization serialVersionUID issue

Tags: serialization, ejb, deserialization, remote-access, serialversionuid

Clinet runs in JVM A , Server Runs in JVM B.
There are all EJB Call from client to server.

Now any of the 2 objects I expect in Client side.

1. Array of `LoanDocument`

   or
2. `BusinessServicesException`

   ```
   public interface LoanViewerServicesLocal extends EJBLocalObject {
      public LoanDocument[] getDocByLoanNumber (String loanNum)
       throws BusinessServicesException; 


   public interface LoanViewerServices extends EJBObject {

       public LoanDocument[] getDocByLoanNumber (String loanNum)
       throws RemoteException,BusinessServicesException;
   ```

Now `BusinessServicesException` extends `CommonException`; `CommonException` extends `ProjectException`; `ProjectException` extends `Exception`.

I specified a `serialVersionUID` value of `1L` in all my 3 exception class (both client and server side ) to avoid de-serialization issue in Client side.

Otherwise I will get

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.abc.common.ProjectException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 354159461886461208, local class serialVersionUID = -5937350397277039691
```

Hence mention 1L in all 3 classes (serialVersionUID =1L) resolve the issue.

Now `LoanDocument` objects extends `CommonDocumentObject` but none of then having `serialVersionUID` or implements `Serializable` interface.

But when we get successful `LoanDocument[]` in client side, I am not getting any `serialVersionUID` related exception due to deserialization?

I tested several times, But I always get same `serialVersionUID` for `LoanDocument` and in `CommonDocumentObject.`

I use below mention code in Server and Clinet and I get always same `serialVersionUID` in both sides.

But always different in case of `BusinessServicesException.`

```
Class loanDocClass = LoanDocument.getClass();
long uid = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(loanDocClass).getSerialVersionUID();
```

Answer (score 0):

> when we get successful `LoanDocument[]` in client side, I am not getting any serialVersionUID related exception due to deserialization?

Because you haven't done any changes to that class between deployment to the server and deployment to the client. In the other cases, you had.